# Sort a Cell Alphabetically in R

Tags: r, dataframe, text, text-mining

Here is my sample data:

```
id                           text
1  1 ['a','good', 'fresh', 'apple']
2  2     ['fresh', 'apple', 'good']
3  3               ['bad', 'apple']

id <- c(1,2,3)
text <- c("['a','good', 'fresh', 'apple']","['fresh', 'apple', 'good']","
['bad', 'apple']")
data.frame(id,text)
```

The text column needs to be sorted alphabetically like bellow:

```
['a','apple', 'fresh', 'good']
['apple', 'fresh', 'good']
['apple', 'bad']
```

I've tried this code, but did not work.

```
data[lapply(strsplit(as.character(data$Lem), ','), sort)),]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the work is getting it in and out of the brackets and quotes. This will not work if the substrings contain commas. I would recommend running it one line at a time to understand what happens in each step.

```
library(stringr)
library(magrittr)
df$sorted_text = str_replace_all(text, "\\[|\\]|'", "") %>%
    str_split(",") %>%
    lapply(str_trim) %>%
    lapply(sort) %>%
    lapply(function(x) paste("'", x, "'", sep = "", collapse = ", ")) %>%
    unlist %>%
    paste0("[", ., "]")
df
#   id                           text                     sorted_text
# 1  1 ['a','good', 'fresh', 'apple'] ['a', 'apple', 'fresh', 'good']
# 2  2     ['fresh', 'apple', 'good']      ['apple', 'fresh', 'good']
# 3  3               ['bad', 'apple']                ['apple', 'bad']
```